# How to write a square function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a code in Matlab to generate a square function as shown in the attached figure. When I tried coding this in Matlab, I got a trapezoid function instead of a perfect square. Please note that the time at tinjb, tinje, and tend is not an exact multiple of the time step (dt). For reference, I have also included a screenshot of the time and mdotf values that are expected.

```
i = 2;
tsim = 0;
flag1 = 0;
flag2 = 0;
mdotL(1) = 0;
tout(1) = 0;
mliqtot = 0;

while tsim < tend
dt = 0.7;
tsim = tsim + dt;
if tsim < tinjb
    mdotl = 0;
elseif tsim >= tinjb && flag1 == 0
    dt = tsim - tinjb;
    tsim = tinjb;
    mdotl = 0;
    flag1 = 1;
elseif tsim == tinjb
    mdotl = 1;
elseif tsim > tinjb && tsim < tinje
    mdotl = 1;
elseif tsim >= tinje && flag2 == 0
    dt = tsim - tinje;
    tsim = tinje;
    mdotl = 1;
    flag2 = 1;
elseif tsim == tinje
    mdotl = 0;
else
    mdotl = 0;
end


mliqtot = mliqtot + mdotl * dt;
tout(i, 1) = tsim;
mdotL(i, 1) = mdotl;
i = i + 1;
tsim = tsim + dt;
end
```

Please help me get this right. This is for my research.

[This is what the square function should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfHBB.png)

[Time and mdotf values that the Matlab code should spit out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4StHM.png)

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the input and what is the required output? The code you posted does nothing like what you describe. The square wave can be simply programmed like `t = 0:0.01:5; sq = t >= 1 & t <= 2;`.

Answer (score 0):

The plot of your code looks like a triangle because of the large timesteps. I think this does everything you explained in your description.

```
clc; clear all; close all;

tStart = 0; %tsim
tEnd = 5; %tend
tStep = 0.7; %dt
a = 1; %tinjb
b = 2; %tinje
x = tStart:tStep:tEnd;
y = rectangularPulse(a,b,x); %mdotf
subplot(2,1,1); plot(x,y);

syms tSym;
subplot(2,1,2); fplot(rectangularPulse(a,b,tSym), [0 5]);
```

Comment: Thanks, Anouk. I will give it a try. Is there a way to extract the x and y-axis information as vectors so that I can populate an excel spreadsheet accordingly?

Comment: On the right side of your screen is the workspace. If you double click on x or y in the workspace it will open like cells similar to Excel.